# Uploaded .wav audio file is unreadable/corrupted in Dropbox

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

Using the dropbox javascript SDK, i'm attempting to upload some .wav audio files to a dropbox folder.

However, the files uploaded are unreadable and give a "audio error" when opened or previewed. The code I'm using is:

```
var Dropbox = require('dropbox').Dropbox;
var dbx = new Dropbox({ accessToken: 'accesstoken' });
    dbx.filesUpload({path: filePath, contents: req.body.file, mode: 'overwrite'})
              .then(function(response) {
                console.log("audio saved!");
                res.sendStatus(200);            
              })
              .catch(function(error) {
                console.error(error);
                response.sendStatus(400);
              });
```

filePath is the folder structure + name of the file, ex: /DropboxRoot/Audio/sounds.wav

For the contents, I have tried many things in the attempt that the data is being uploaded in the wrong format. So far I've tried:

1. Blob - Blob(123456){size:123456, type:"audio/wav"}
2. ArrayBuffer

Am I uploading the data incorrectly? The audio blob can be used successfully as audio before being sent to the server.

I record the audio using this [free code](https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html#) and play it back by loading it to the source of an Audio element like so:

```
<audio controls>
              <source src="" type="audio/wav" />
            </audio>
```

The "source" is set to `var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob)`

Comment: `The audio blob can be used successfully as audio before being sent to the server.` how are you both recording / generating this audio blob, then how are you playing it back? Maybe DropBox thinks it's a WAV, but its actually an MP3? Maybe it doesnt even have the proper file headers for a WAV, but is just the raw binary data?

Comment: @MattClark See updated question

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Audio-files-uploaded-give-quot-audio-error-has-occurred-quot-and/m-p/275413#M16445 ]